# iphone - app crash in a form

Tags: ios, forms, nsstring

In my app, I have a view where user have to fill a form. But, sometime the app crash here, in this function, that simple cacth the value field and built a url to give

```
-(NSString*)urlToUpload{

    NSString *string1 =[[NSString alloc]init];
    string1= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"?nombre="];
    NSString *string2 =  [string1 stringByAppendingString:nameAdded];

//crash here

    NSString *string3 =  [string2 stringByAppendingString:@"&horario="];
    NSString *string4 =  [string3 stringByAppendingString:horarioAdded];


    NSString *string5 =  [string4 stringByAppendingString:@"&info="];
    NSString *string6 =  [string5 stringByAppendingString:infoAdded];

    NSString *string7 =  [string6 stringByAppendingString:@"&offerta="];
    NSString *string8 =  [string7 stringByAppendingString:offertaAdded];

    NSString *lat_string = [[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%f",locationToUpload2.latitude] autorelease];
    NSString *lon_string = [[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%f",locationToUpload2.longitude] autorelease];

    NSString *string9 =  [string8 stringByAppendingString:@"&latitude="];
    NSString *string10 =  [string9 stringByAppendingString:lat_string];

    NSString *string11 =  [string10 stringByAppendingString:@"&longitude="];
    NSString *string12 =  [string11 stringByAppendingString:lon_string];


    NSString *url1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://myserverside/mysql_up.php"];

    NSString *url =  [url1 stringByAppendingString:string12];



    return url;
}
```

EDIT:

It seems problem appers on nameAdded when there is a white space into textField(i.e. MisterB not crash, Mister B  yes ). 
But I am using:

```
nameAdded =[[nameField.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

and  NSLOg give of nameAdded is Mister%20B.

The crash still appearing...

Comment: There is quite a lot wrong with this code from what I see but my first guess at what is wrong would be "nameAdded" in the line that crashes. Is that a property?

Comment: See http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1

Comment: thanks maddy, I do not know that tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

Just use a single `stringWithFormat:`:

```
- (NSString *)urlToUpload {
    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://myserverside/mysql_up.php?nombre=%@&horario=%@&info=%@&offerta=%@&latitude=%f&longitude=%f",
       [nameAdded stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],
       [horarioAdded stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],
       [infoAdded stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],
       [offertaAdded stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],
       locationToUpload2.latitude, locationToUpload2.longitude];

    return url;
}
```

Make sure the referenced variables are valid.

In your original code there is no need to alloc/init an NSString then assign another string to the same variable. That's a memory leak (`string1`).

If you really want to structure your code the way you have it, at least use an `NSMutableString` and append to that one mutable string. Creating over a dozen `NSString` variables is the wrong way to do it.

**Updated**: Ensure each of the strings added to the URL are properly escaped.

Comment: +1 for much more concise code; but if the OP is using ARC, then the compiler should be inserting a `release` on `string1` after the first alloc/init.  Quick test with disassembly suggests that it does.

Comment: @NSBum Since the OP's code has calls to `autorelease` we know that ARC is not being used.

Comment: oops - didn't scroll far enough to the right to see the `autorelease` calls.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like nameAdded may be the cause of your problems. Is it nil at that point?

Also

1. You are allocating a string, setting it to string1 and then immediately setting string1 to the class function stringWithFormat which allocates another string. Also you are using stringWithFormat but you aren't using any format so you could simply use NSString *string1 = @"?nombre=";
2. Rather than declaring all of those variables you should just use NSMutableString and build it all in one variabl

Comment: NSMutableString is only needed when you want to modify a string like insert/delete a character. `NSString *s = @"first item";` and then simply `s = [s stringAppendingString:@"xyz"];` and `s = [s stringByAppendigFormat:@"%f", var];` works very well.

Comment: @ott-- Using `NSMutableString` to append lots of pieces together is far more efficient than appending a bunch of immutable strings into separate variables.

Comment: @maddy As you showed in your answer, using only one NSString is even more efficient - it doesn't need a method of its own.

Comment: Tx rooster117. It seems probleam apper when there is a white space into nameadded. I edit my question...